# no backup selected for restore sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

1. I am trying to restore db from my db backup file when i select and add the db .bak file
2. I have seen that error "No back upset selected to be restored"
3. I also tried from script to restore it but failed.

kindly tell me some effective way to do that??

I have already tried this  but failed

```
RESTORE DATABASE <Your Database>
FROM DISK='<the path to your backup file>\<Your Database>.bak'
```

Comment: What is the error message received when executing `RESTORE DATABASE ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `RESTORE HEADERONLY` to see if there are several backup sets in your bak file

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY
FROM DISK='<the path to your backup file>\<Your Database>.bak'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx

and if there are several sets, choose the one you want :

```
RESTORE DATABASE <Your Database>
FROM DISK='<the path to your backup file>\<Your Database>.bak'
WITH FILE = <you set number>;
```

Comment: `if there are several sets..` Then it will not throw a `No back upset selected to be restored` exception